# Attribute value must be constant in retrofit Header

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-native-library

I I tried to call the API key that I created with nativeLib, but when it is called in the retrofit header it can't be executed and there is a message "**Attribute value must be constant"**

APIInterface

```
String RAPID_API_KEY = NativeLib.apiKey();
String RAPID_API_HOST = NativeLib.apiHost();

@Headers({RAPID_API_KEY, RAPID_API_HOST}) // Error message in this line
@GET
Call<Post>getVideoByUrl(@Url String url, @Query("url") String inputUrl);
```

is there a solution for this problem? I really appreciate whatever the answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation attribute value must be known at compile-time, only inlined compile-time constants are allowed, like this:

```
/* static final */ String RAPID_API_KEY = "X-Header-Name: RtaW4YWRtaYWucG..."
/* static final */ String RAPID_API_KEY = "X-Header-Name: " + "RtaW4YWRtaYWucG..."
/* static final */ String RAPID_API_KEY = "X-Header-Name: " + Constants.API_KEY /* API_KEY = "RtaW4YWRtaYWucG..." */
```

but not

```
String RAPID_API_KEY = NativeLib.apiKey(); /* Here compiler can't compute NativeLib.apiKey() value */
```

Alternatively, you can pass header in parameter dynamically using [@Header](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Header.html) or [@HeaderMap](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/HeaderMap.html)

```
@GET
Call<Post> getVideoByUrl(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
                         @Url String url,
                         @Query("url") String inputUrl);
...
final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Key Header Name", NativeLib.apiKey());
headers.put("Host Header Name", NativeLib.apiHost());
...
api.getVideoByUrl(headers, ...);
```

also you can use an OkHttp interceptor if you want to [add the header to all requests.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add%20headers%20to%20OkHttp%20request%20interceptor)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add **""** before `NativeLib.apiKey();` and same in `NativeLib.apiHost();`. please refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39157786/12660050 and [In Java why this error: 'attribute value must be constant'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28031784/12660050)

Comment: I've tried String RAPID_API_KEY = "" + NativeLib.apiKey(); but the result is still the same

Comment: you have given the key of headers value ? Like @Headers("Key Name: RAPID_API_KEY")